# How do I fix the error: "Cannot bind positional parameters because no names were given"

Tags: powershell

I got this error today in my script and there's nothing online I could find in the search engine that had the answer, so I'm posting a question and answering it here.

Error:

> ```
> Cannot bind positional parameters because no names were given.
> ```

Here's my script:

```
function some_f {
    param(
        [parameter(position = 0
        )]
        [string]$param_1,

        [parameter(position = 0
        )]
        [string]$param_2
    )
    "in f: param_1 = '$param_1'; param_2 = '$param_2'"
}


some_f 'str_1' 'str_2'
"got here"
```

output:

> ```
> PS c:\...\powershell> myscript.ps1
> some_f : Cannot bind positional parameters because no names were given.
> At E:\a_no_backup\dl\M_M\usb_drive_copy\tech\windows_10\powershell\args_arguments_parameters_example_no_name_given_error.ps1:19 char:1
> + some_f 'str_1' 'str_2'
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [some_f], ParameterBindingException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousPositionalParameterNoName,some_f
> ```

The types of the parameters don't matter, but you will only likely make the error on a more complex script, so the types here hint at that condition.

Also, if you comment out the *call* to `some_f` there is **no error**

```
function some_f {
    param(
        [parameter(position = 0
        )]
        [string]$param_1,

        [parameter(position = 0
        )]
        [string]$param_2
    )
    "in f: param_1 = '$param_1'; param_2 = '$param_2'"
}


#some_f 'str_1' 'str_2'
"got here"
```

output:

> ```
> PS c:\...\powershell> myscript.ps1
> got here
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The error is that the function has two parameters with the same `position` number `0`:

> ```
> position = 0
> position = 0
> ```

There's a clue in this error ID:

> FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousPositionalParameterNoName

It's an easy mistake when your code is more complicated.

It happened to me when I had (simplified) 2 parameters, 1 mandatory, and 1 optional, and added another parameter--the new 2nd parameter, mandatory, now for a total of 3 parameters. The final parameter was optional and not often used, so it was not top of mind as I made my edit.

Original function:

```
function some_f {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory,
        position = 0
        )]
        [string]$param_1,

        [parameter(Mandatory = $false,
        position = 1
        )]
        [string]$optional
    )
    "in f: param_1 = '$param_1'; optional = '$optional'"
}


some_f 'a_str'
some_f 'a_str' 'opt_str'
"got here"
```

Output:

> ```
> in f: param_1 = 'a_str'; optional = ''
> in f: param_1 = 'a_str'; optional = 'opt_str'
> got here
> ```

After editing my powershell code:

```
function some_f {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory,
        position = 0
        )]
        [string]$param_1,

        [parameter(Mandatory,    # new
        position = 1             # new
        )]                       # new
        [string]$new_param,      # new

        [parameter(Mandatory = $false,
        position = 1
        )]
        [string]$optional
    )
    "in f: param_1 = '$param_1'; new_param = '$new_param'; optional = '$optional'"
}

some_f 'a_str' '2nd_str'
some_f 'a_str' '2nd_str' 'opt_str'
"got here"
```

Output of edited code with error:

> ```
> PS c:\...\powershell> edited_script.ps1
> some_f : Cannot bind positional parameters because no names were given.
> At E:\a_no_backup\dl\M_M\usb_drive_copy\tech\windows_10\powershell\args_arguments_parameters_example_no_name_given_error_3_after.ps1:26 char:1
> + some_f 'a_str' '2nd_str'
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [some_f], ParameterBindingException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousPositionalParameterNoName,some_f
>  
> some_f : Cannot bind positional parameters because no names were given.
> At E:\a_no_backup\dl\M_M\usb_drive_copy\tech\windows_10\powershell\args_arguments_parameters_example_no_name_given_error_3_after.ps1:27 char:1
> + some_f 'a_str' '2nd_str' 'opt_str'
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [some_f], ParameterBindingException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousPositionalParameterNoName,some_f
>  
> got here
> ```

Some observations:

- The error is in the definition of the code of my user-defined function. It would have been preferable had the powershell developers detected that syntax error in the definition of the function itself and pointed us to those lines of code, rather than silently accepting the buggy code if never called, and then reporting the call to the function in the error message, instead of the function definition.
- If I were to speculate, I might guess that the function code is being accepted by the parser without detecting the error, however as a result creating an internal structure that is functionally corrupt, and that corruption is detected as a call with the wrong parameters at function call time. Of course you can't call this function correctly, it's parameters make no functional sense (as written, with the bug in there).
- If so, this might be a bug in powershell itself.

**EDIT:**

After further consideration prompted by @Santiago Squarzon's phrasing, and the particular phrasing of the error message "no names were given," I wondered if two parameters with the same position value was legal.

According to the parser, it appears that while duplicating position values deems the function un-callable using *unnamed* position parameters (which still might be considered a bug in some quarters), it is still callable using *named* parameters. And a `ParameterSet` is not needed to distinguish them.

Example code:

```
function some_f {
    param(
        [parameter(position = 0
        )]
        [string]$param_1,

        [parameter(position = 0
        )]
        [string]$param_2
    )
    "in f: param_1 = '$param_1'; param_2 = '$param_2'"
}


some_f 'str_1' 'str_2'        # error
some_f -param_1 'str_1'       # ok
some_f -param_2 'str_2'       # ok
some_f -param_1 'str_1' -param_2 'str_2'       # ok
"got here"
```

Output:

```
PS c:\...\powershell> myscript2.ps1
some_f : Cannot bind positional parameters because no names were given.
At E:\a_no_backup\dl\M_M\usb_drive_copy\tech\windows_10\powershell\args_arguments_parameters_example_no_name_given_error.ps1:19 char:1
+ some_f 'str_1' 'str_2'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [some_f], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousPositionalParameterNoName,some_f
 
in f: param_1 = 'str_1'; param_2 = ''
in f: param_1 = ''; param_2 = 'str_2'
in f: param_1 = 'str_1'; param_2 = 'str_2'
got here
```

So it's legal? And undocumented?

Comment: If you believe the parser should not allow you to have 2 parameters with the same position I invite you to post an issue on Github https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues